# How to get the text of view in onintercepttouchevent

Tags: android

I have an application code which consists of a relative layout, and a table and inside it a set of buttons are there. I need to handle onintercepttouchevent, what I want to do is I want to retrieve the text of the button which was clicked and use its text to set it in a string. but I want to know how to implement the onintercepttouchevent and ontouchevent methods for each and every button and the parent layout. I want to know how to retrieve the text of the button and how to handle various actions like DOWN, MOVE and UP events. so please give me a clear example of how to achieve this. how to implement the onintercepttouchevent method with an example.

here is my code

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity 
implements OnInitListener,OnTouchListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Handler mhandler = new Handler();
    Button mybtn[] = new Button[10];
    // int[] mybtn1 = new int[] {R.id.btn0,R.id.btn1,R.id.btn2,R.id.btn11};

    Button select_btn, home_btn;
    View l;
    EditText et;
    Bundle b;
    Intent in;
    int var = 0;
    int pass = 1;
    int quit = 1;
    int current = 0;
    boolean status = false;
    private int MY_DATA_CHECKCODE = 0;
    private TextToSpeech tts = null;
    Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // select_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        // home_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
        et.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        l = (View) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        b = new Bundle();


        for (int i = 0; i < mybtn.length; i++) {
            String btnid = "btn" + i;
            int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id",
                    getPackageName());
            mybtn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resid);
            mybtn[i].setOnTouchListener(this);

        }


    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();

        // final float x = ev.getX();

        switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            // Remember each down event,
            // as it is needed in startDragging above
            // mLastMotionX = x;
            status = false;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            status = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            status = false;
            break;
        }
        // Whilst dragging, we return true in order to dispatch
        // the MotionEvent to our onTouchEvent method below.
        // return mIsDragging;
        return status;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (!status) {
            // Not in dragging mode, so no tyaction taken
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        // float x = ev.getX();

        switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // et.setText("down android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Move the object.
            // doDrag(x);
            // Call back to user
            // callMoveCallback(x);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // stopDragging(x);
            // et.setText("down android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

But I don't know , how to implement the above two methods for each and every Button and the parent layout. I also want to know how to retrieve the text of the button, which is touched. I have tried the ontouch(MotionEvent, View) method. Can I do it using above two methods? How to do it?

And one more thing:

```
View l = (View)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
```

Is it fine? How to retrieve the layouts in android? Inside it I have table and inside it I have buttons, how to handle them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use onClickListener instead of onTouchListener

```
mybtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then, in your onClick listener you could get the button string or id and do the things you want.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    String buttontext = (String) ((Button) v).getText();

    int id = v.getId();

    switch(id)
    {
    case R.id.button1
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion, but it is not the solution for my problem. instead of clicking when user touches the button then the text should be set.i want to handle DOWN, MOVE, UP events but not the clicking events. if possible please provide me a clear example of using onintercepttouchevent with an example